# saving state between pages when creating a windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I've been following the Create your first Windows Store app using C# or Visual Basic tutorials provided by Microsoft but am having some problems saving state when navigating between pages.

[Create your first Windows Store app using C# or Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974581.aspx)

[Part 3: Navigation, layout, and views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215600.aspx)

Basically I've noticed that if I navigate from the main page to the photo page select a photo, navigate back to the main page and then go to the photo page again it doesn't remember the photo that was selected.  I'm using the following code to navigate to the photo page from the main page.

```
private void photoPageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PhotoPage));
}
```

In the photo page the loadstate method is

```
protected async override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
    if (pageState != null && pageState.ContainsKey("mruToken"))
    {
        object value = null;
        if (pageState.TryGetValue("mruToken", out value))
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                mruToken = value.ToString();

                // Open the file via the token that you stored when adding this file into the MRU list.
                Windows.Storage.StorageFile file =
                    await Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.GetFileAsync(mruToken);

                if (file != null)
                {
                    // Open a stream for the selected file.
                    Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileStream =
                        await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

                    // Set the image source to a bitmap.
                    Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bitmapImage =
                        new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();

                    bitmapImage.SetSource(fileStream);
                    displayImage.Source = bitmapImage;

                    // Set the data context for the page.
                    this.DataContext = file;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The photo page save state is

```
protected override void SaveState(Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mruToken))
    {
        pageState["mruToken"] = mruToken; 
    }
}
```

I've noticed that the pagestate is always null when navigated to.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that SaveState is invoked and pageState set when navigating from the PhotoPage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this tutorial too and I found one solution to save the state across pages navigation.

First, override the **OnNavigatedFrom** in order to save the file token into State Frame:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

    var state = SuspensionManager.SessionStateForFrame(this.Frame);
    state["mruToken"] = mruToken;
}
```

Override the **OnNavigatedTo** in order to load the token from the state:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    var state = SuspensionManager.SessionStateForFrame(this.Frame);
    if (state != null && state.ContainsKey("mruToken"))
    {
        object value = null;

        if (state.TryGetValue("mruToken", out value))
        {
           // the same code as LoadState to retrieve the image  
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, I wrote another function to retrieve the image so it can be used in both **LoadState** and **OnNavigatedTo** methods.

```
private async void restoreImage(object value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        mruToken = value.ToString();

        // Open the file via the token that you stored when adding this file into the MRU list.
        Windows.Storage.StorageFile file =
            await Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList.GetFileAsync(mruToken);

        if (file != null)
        {
            // Open a stream for the selected file.
            Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileStream =
                await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

            // Set the image source to a bitmap.
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bitmapImage =
                new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();

            bitmapImage.SetSource(fileStream);
            displayImage.Source = bitmapImage;

            // Set the data context for the page.
            this.DataContext = file;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Enable **`NavigationCacheMode`** property of the page and add **`NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"`**

### OR

Enable it by properties panel.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from the NavigationHelper OnNavigateTo method

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var frameState = SuspensionManager.SessionStateForFrame(this.Frame);
        this._pageKey = "Page-" + this.Frame.BackStackDepth;

        if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)
        {
            // Clear existing state for forward navigation when adding a new page to the
            // navigation stack
            var nextPageKey = this._pageKey;
            int nextPageIndex = this.Frame.BackStackDepth;
            while (frameState.Remove(nextPageKey))
            {
                nextPageIndex++;
                nextPageKey = "Page-" + nextPageIndex;
            }

            // Pass the navigation parameter to the new page
            if (this.LoadState != null)
            {
                this.LoadState(this, new LoadStateEventArgs(e.Parameter, null));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Pass the navigation parameter and preserved page state to the page, using
            // the same strategy for loading suspended state and recreating pages discarded
            // from cache
            if (this.LoadState != null)
            {
                this.LoadState(this, new LoadStateEventArgs(e.Parameter, (Dictionary<String, Object>)frameState[this._pageKey]));
            }
        }
    }
```

`if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.New)` if always true because `Frame` by default creates a new instance of the `Page`. See [`Frame` Class Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.aspx). So The `LoadState` event handler is always called with a null state parameter

```
if (this.LoadState != null)
{
    this.LoadState(this, new LoadStateEventArgs(e.Parameter, null));
}
```

Now if you look at the complete code for [PhotoPage.xaml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj676796.aspx) very closely you will notice that in the page header there is this `NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"` that is what makes it `PhotoPage` works.

There no need for all that code about saving states in the `Page`. The `Frame class` does that for you when the `Page` sets its `NavigationCacheMode`.